# Mortal infrastructure

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

A straight forward question as I had a discussion there with a player of mine:

> Infrastructure is a physical arrangement of materials and manpower. It
>   is the vacuum cleaner in the closet that could be called upon at any
>   time. It is the fleet of snowplows in the city parking lot and those
>   hired to drive them (as well as all the infrastructure that supports
>   snow removal — from the budget to the plow manufacturer).

is in the core rules of demons page 64. Now my question is can mortals only be part of an infrastructure or can they also be infrastructure themselves?

As example:
A building that is infrastructure (with rooms and elevators being logistics infrastructure) the human parts are used to remove no longer used elements (inhabitants) and to put them where they can be of some need (feeding the gears). These human parts would these be infrastructure or only parts of an infrastructure or nothing there at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the passage you quoted:

> Infrastructure is […] the fleet of snowplows in the city parking lot **and those hired to drive them**

So yes, the people in your scenario would form *part* of the infrastructure. People need to be part of some useful system to be counted as infrastructure, and aren't infrastructure all by themselves when not part of a useful system.